# How do keep CustomDialog when its activity is finished?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a custom dialog which is displaying fine, but it immediately gets closed because its activity's finish method is called immediately after it's displayed. Previously, I was using a toast message, and this had no problem staying up in the same circumstances.

I'm pretty sure the problem is that the custom dialog, unlike the Toast message, "belongs" to the Activity, so when the activity goes away, the dialog goes away too. I was thinking of adding listener with setOnShowListener, but I don't think that will work - unless the listener somehow blocks the finish. I could add a timer delay, but that's not a very attractive solution. What is a good solution here?

Comment: But why is the activity being finished? Yes you could display the activity as a dialog but alternatively I wonder why the `finish` can't be avoided and then you simply call `finish` on return from the custom dialog.

Comment: That's the problem - I am calling finish after the call to show the dialog.

Comment: Then you should call `finish` as per other answer or theme as a dialog, again as per the other answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better to display the another activity as a dialog.

Simply add this to the new activity which should be displayed as a dialog,

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

Comment: yup. thanks Doug. or use    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

Comment: Yes, this is preferable. You can use the standard activity apis and it encapsulates the logic for the dialog into the activity. Thanks.